# iMovie error when trying to upload to YouTube

Tags: api, youtube, quote, imovie

iMovie will not allow me to upload a video to YouTube because it says I exceeded my quote. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I know that iMovie have some bugs uploading directly to youtube... I suggest exporting a regular Quicktime files (choose mpeg4 codec) and then upload this exported file inside youtube website